# Unable to hot reload JHipster application

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, jhipster

This is the first time I'm using jhipster. I'm trying to hot reload the application but I get a runtime Thymeleaf exception. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

But if I deploy the war in tomcat for instance works ok. It's just trying to hot reload in Jetty container.

```
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.reloader.listener.JHipsterHandlerMappingListener - Looking up handler method for path /
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.reloader.listener.JHipsterHandlerMappingListener - Did not find handler method for [/]

[ERROR] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][qtp1943492650-26 - /] Exception processing template "error": Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
[WARN] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler - EXCEPTION 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:575) [jetty-security-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:276) ~[jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:112) ~[jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:86) ~[jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:351) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:419) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:164) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:164) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.sendError(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:164) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter$StatusExposingServletResponse.sendError(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:125) [metrics-servlet-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:126) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97) [metrics-servlet-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:257) [spring-boot-actuator-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) [jetty-security-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) [jetty-servlet-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:366) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) [jetty-http-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) [jetty-http-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) [jetty-io-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) [jetty-io-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-8.1.15.v20140411.jar:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I had a multi-module IDEA project and working directory set in the RUN configuration was the main ROOT project and not the sub-module. Changing it the right directory fixed the problem.